# Create a dirty flag binding in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js

I'm trying to create a binding handler which allows me to track if any of the values used in the binding has changed:

```
<div id="container1" data-bind="dirty: $root.container1Dirty">
    <span data-bind="visible: $root.container1Dirty">*</span>

    <label>
        Text 1
        <input data-bind="value: $root.text1" />
    </label>
</div>
```

So far I tried the following:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dirty = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var counter = 0;
        var dirtyObservable = valueAccessor();
        var appliedBindings = false;

        var computed = ko.computed(function() {
            if (!appliedBindings) {
                // I was hoping this would subscribe all the used observables
                ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(bindingContext, element);
                appliedBindings = true;
            }
            // make sure subscribe is triggered by returning a new value
            return counter++; 
        });
        computed.subscribe(function() {
            dirtyObservable(true);
        });

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};
```

I was hoping `ko.applyBindingsToDescendants` would subscribe the observables used in all the bindings within that container. This however doesn't seem to be the case; see http://jsfiddle.net/F3uMr/1/.

Is there another way to achieve this? Or would it be better to create a ViewModel for each container and then use the [dirty flag](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/05/creating-smart-dirty-flag-in-knockoutjs.html)?

Comment: @michaelpapworth I already know how to track changes of ViewModels, but in this case I'd like to subscribe to all the observables used within a specific element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now I'm manually providing all the observables to track:

```
<div id="container1" data-bind="
    dirty: {
        flag: 'container1Dirty',
        target: [$root.text1]
    }">
    <span data-bind="visible: container1Dirty">*</span>

    <label>
        Text 1
        <input data-bind="value: $root.text1" />
    </label>
</div>
```

With the following binding handler:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.dirty = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel, bindingContext) {

        var data = valueAccessor();
        var dirtyObservable = ko.observable(false);
        var orgValue = ko.toJSON(data.target);

        var extraBinding = {};
        extraBinding[data.flag || 'dirty'] = dirtyObservable;

        var innerBindingContext = bindingContext.extend(extraBinding);
        ko.applyBindingsToDescendants(innerBindingContext, element);

        var dirty = ko.computed(function() {
            return orgValue !== ko.toJSON(data.target);
        });

        dirty.subscribe(function(isDirty) {
            dirtyObservable(isDirty);
        });

        return { controlsDescendantBindings: true };
    }
};

ko.applyBindings({
    text1: ko.observable('text1'),
    text2: ko.observable('text2')
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ZdS3W/

This isn't really the solution I hoped for since I now have to manually provide all the observables I want to track vs. automatically finding all the used observables. So I'm still open for a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but you can wrap the dirty flag into a 'base class' and keep all of the logic shared between view models there. For example:

**[Fiddle is here](http://jsfiddle.net/cChF9/)**

```
<input type='text' data-bind="value: textBox, event: { keyup: isDirty }">
<input type='button' value='click me if you can' data-bind="click: save, ,enable: isDirty"> 

var BaseViewModel = function (saveUrl, data) {
    var self;
    this.isDirty = ko.observable(false);
    this.save = function(){
        var jsData = ko.toJS(data);
        alert('save: ' + jsData.textBox);
    };
};

var pageViewModel = function(){
    var self = this;

    this.textBox = ko.observable('');
    ko.utils.extend(self, new BaseViewModel('url for save', {textBox: self.textBox}));
}

ko.applyBindings(new pageViewModel());
```

If you don't want to specify events and just apply the 'dirty' check to all of the observables, you can try something like this: **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XJ93/1/)**

Comment: This doesn't really help me. I'd like to be able to automatically detect changes within an element without having to add things like `keyup: isDirty` to all the input elements.

Comment: I updated the answer to continue with the same pattern, but remove the event from the input...

Comment: This way you still need to manually subscribe to all the observables you want to watch. But I want to automatically watch/subscribe all the observables used in a specific container (element) by applying a custom binding.